# Apache Http Server 2.2.22 (Loadbalancing) installation on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

Ubuntu 12.0.4
httpd-2.2.22.tar

Having following error when building.

Error 1 (when compiling):

```
#./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apacheHttpServer3 --enable-modules=proxy
#make install
ibapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl
libtool: link: cannot find the library `/root/Downloads/httpd-2.2.22/srclib/apr-util/xml/expat/libexpat.la' or unhandled argument `/root/Downloads/httpd-2.2.22/srclib/apr-util/xml/expat/libexpat.la'
make[2]: *** [libaprutil-1.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/httpd-2.2.22/srclib/apr-util'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/httpd-2.2.22/srclib'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Is there a compact solution for this different from what  I have answer as follow.

Solution 1:

```
cd Downloads/httpd-2.2.22/srclib/apr-util/xml/expat/
./configure
make
cp libexpat.la /usr/lib/
```

Error 2 (when running): braries: libexpat.so.0: cannot open share
Solution:

```
ln -s libexpat.so  /usr/lib/libexpat.so.0
```

this command should be executed each time when starting and stopping server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not answer your question, but why are you building version 2.2.22 from source? The package from ubuntu is the [same version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/apache2). Just run:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```